# Token for email includes name of field

Tags: 6, webforms, emails, tokens

Ok, so I've got this webform sending an email upon correct submission.

I'm trying to format the email so that it can send to a user who submits a form.

This email would say something like "Hi, Name, thanks for submission!"

I am trying to use the following:

```
<p>Hi %email[name]</p>
```

And the email is coming out like this:

Hi

name:

PersonNameHere

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the name come out without the field name?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Hi, I'm %value[Name]!</p>
```

works perfectly.